# Is there always a non-cyclic abelian subgroup of S2n with order n^2?

Tags: abstract-algebra, computational-algebra

Let $ n \in N$. Does there always exist a non-cyclic abelian subgroup of $S_{2n}$, the symmetric group on 2n letters,   with $n^2$ elements? How could a computer give an example of such subgroup in? For instance in $S_6$ how could a computer find a non-cyclic abelian subgroup with order 9?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can take $\langle (12\cdots n), ((n+1)\cdots 2n)\rangle$ : this is a group isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$.

Comment: where $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^2$ is the first group to look for under the constraints non-cyclic abelian of order $n^2$ if it shall work for all $n$ ...

Comment: @jd123 It is the subgroup **generated** by those two elements. In particular, it contains all products and powers of those elements.